# How do you make a image as your submit Button in yii2

Tags: yii2

I am new to yii and want to created a search form where if a user fills in the field and then click on a submit button which is an image it will be directed to a another page showing the results.  I couldn't find anywhere where the `Html::submitButton()` has the option of using an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easly try with a background image in style option :

```
 echo Button::Widget([
    'label'=>'label',
    'options'=>['style' => 'background: url(myimage.png)'],
    'url' => Url::toRoute(['/controller/action']),
 ]);
```

ot for submit button

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['style' => 'background: url(myimage.png)'])?>
```

Comment: This worked! but is there an way  to resize the image button when I change the screen size of the browser like **img-responsive**

Comment: if the answer is useful please rate it as usef   and/or mark as accepted. For the img-resposive like question ... you can apply the style you need inside the style eg:  'style' => 'background: url(myimage.png); width: 100%; height: 100%' .. This value are only sample you should investigate what yo need/prefer.

Comment: I tried different configurations of width and height etc and still the image does not resize similar to when I use img-responsive. It is probably because it is now a button and not a image. Is there any other option to using a image as your submit button and it will also resize when the browser screen resizes.

Comment: You use bootstrap 3 ?